# How to test my published LEX bot on a REST CLIENT

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have created my lex bot and published it. I am now trying to test it out from a rest client.

The idea is once working from rest client ,i can integrate this with my custom UI using rest calls.

[image]

I am using this request body from posttext as per this link 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html​

When i am using  this from rest client i am getting Missing Authentication Token.

[image]

The end point url used is https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Should i add something in the authorization header like AWS Signature or something else to make this work.

Comment: Did you check out [Authentication and Access Control for Amazon Lex](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/auth-and-access-control.html)?

Answer (score 12):

You need to include an AWS Signature in the Authorization tab, containing the details of an IAM user that has access to run your Lex bot.

Steps:
1. In AWS go to IAM -> Users -> Add User

[image]

2. Give it a Username like "myBotUser" and select an Access Type of "Programmatic access". Hit Next:Permissions.

[image]

3. Hit Create Group to create a group to give permissions to the user.

[image]

4. Give it a name and then filter the policies for Lex - and select "AmazonLexReadOnly" and "AmazonLexRunBotsOnly".

[image]

Hit Create Group.

5. Then hit "Next: Review".
6. Then hit "Create User" - and your IAM user is ready. You'll see an Access key ID and a Secret Access Key.
7. In Postman, in Authorization, select AWS Signature and enter in the Access key ID and the Secret Access Key, along with an AWS Region of "us-east-1" and a Service Name of "lex":

[image]

8. Make sure you're body is as required (here I'm just sending text):

[image]

Hit Send and you should get a response like this:

```
{
    "dialogState": "Fulfilled",
    "intentName": "yourIntentName",
    "message": "A response for that intent",
    "responseCard": null,
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "slotToElicit": null,
    "slots": {}
}
```

**Update**

Note also - the POST url would be in format:

```
https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bot/MyBotName/alias/myMyAlias/user/aUniqueUserID/text and it should be a POST
```

Also make sure the header Content-Type is application/json, as is the body.

Comment: Did all this . i am getting this error "Error while sending request:Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' is not a valid http header field value" . Is this because the endpoint url is not correct? I f so what should be the right url to call a published lex bot having bot name and alias name.

Comment: i am using the same.. i have added the screen shot in the question

Comment: {
   "inputText": "i want to raise a ticket",
   "sessionAttributes": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   }
}

Comment: the request is not going i guess

Comment: Hmm. Can you post the postman json of the request (just remove the keys if they're in it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149002/discussion-between-lost-coder-and-andyos).

Comment: POST /bot/test/alias/lexTestChat/user/unique123r/text HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com​
X-Amz-Date: 20170712T123140Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxx/20170712/us-east-1/lex/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 46f48b78-ab05-1f1b-5f37-bceb4e02dc9e

{
   "inputText": "i want to raise a ticket",
   "sessionAttributes": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   }
}

Comment: is there anything specific in user we have to give or can it be any random value ?

Comment: See the chat discussion

Comment: Check the chat, I've posted json for postman that should work